# TaskBar buttons show icon but no text

Tags: taskbar, windows-server-2008, icons

I installed Windows Server 2008 R2 (but I believe this question stil belongs here and not on serverfault) and the default look is one in which the taskbar buttons (*taskbar*, not notification icons) only show the icon and not the text.  I prefer it where the buttons show both the icon and the text.  How can I make this so?

[image]

I have 4 open programs: *Chrome*, *Task Manager*, *CMD Prompt*, *Windows Explorer*.
None of the programs are pinned.

I want to see the text beside each program like I'm used to from every previous version of windows.

Comment: Are you asking for labels for the pinned programs, or the programs that are minimized? I think you ruled out the Systray icons in the right hand corner.

Comment: Right, click one of the taskbar buttons and see if it shows the title of the window.

Comment: @Synetech, I am not talking about pinned programs.  Just minimized (or normal, or maximized) taskbar buttons.  (they all take up a slot in the taskbar as a button) They are not showing any text, making it difficult for me to figure out what they are.

Comment: @Synetech, I do not understand what you mean.  When I right-click on the taskbar button, I get the same popup menu I always get:  The name of the program, the ability to pin, and the ability to close the window.

Comment: I didn’t say right-click, I said I said right, as in what KCotreau said. What about non-minimized windows? Do they have text in their buttons?

Comment: @Synetech, in my experience the taskbar buttons always show text whether they are minimized, normal, or maximized.  Equally, here they do *not* shot text whether they are minimized, normal, or maximized.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I had forgotten about the `Taskbar buttons` section of the Taskbar settings.  It was set to `Always combine, hide labels` and of course it was doing exactly that.

[image]

I changed it to `Never combine` and now it's working like I wanted it to.

Comment: Aha, the picture makes it clear what the problem is. When you have that option enabled and have a lot of instances of the window open, it does exactly that. Screenshots are good.